# Perl regex skipping every other line

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to extract the first complete number on each line from a text file like this:

```
8 gcaggcaaactgcgataataaaaggctgtttcaacagcggagtggattgt 1.5307684822361e-176
11 tttacccagtgagtttgaagcaaggatcttttagtttaccgaaaaatgag 3.22210306380202e-293
14 agcaatagcgcgaacagacaacctcatcagtctaccgcgcaccctttccc 1.32107737963584e-52
20 agtgacagggaaaggcgatcgcggctttacgatcagagatcggtgtcggt 0.942504155078175
30 tccggagactttcgattgcatgcaattcaccatcataccctcttgccctc 0
45 actgagcccctgacgctggccagtgtagcgctgtgaagtcccctctcagg 9.49147409471272e-307
53 gaaccgagcgatcgctgctgccattgtctcgccttctgccgaggaatgcc 2.15850303270505e-28
```

using the regex in the following code:

```
my $id = undef;
while (my $line = <INFILE>){
  chomp $line;
  if ($line =~ /\A([0-9]+)/){
      $id = $1;
  }
print OUTFILE "$id\n";
$line = <INFILE>;
chomp $line;
}
```

The output I'm getting only includes every other line:

```
8
14
30
53
```

I've tried printing out every line without doing the match, and everything is there.  Once I add the regex, it skips every other line.  Any ideas why it's doing this?

Comment: I'm not familair with Perl, but isn't it easier to use the multi-line flag in the regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reading from the `INFILE` handle twice, once in the `while` condition, and once at the end of the loop.

Remove, the final read:

```
my $id = undef;
while (my $line = <INFILE>){
  chomp $line;
  if ($line =~ /\A([0-9]+)/){
      $id = $1;
  }
  print OUTFILE "$id\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I just realized how obvious my mistake was.

Comment: Meh... it's only obvious when you haven't been staring at it for hours :o)

Answer (score 1):

You are skipping file lines

```
   while (my $line = <INFILE>) {   # Reading line once
       chomp $line;   
       if ($line =~ /\A([0-9]+)/){       
          $id = $1;   
       } 
       print OUTFILE "$id\n";
       $line = <INFILE>;   # Reading line again!!!!!

   }
```

because you are calling

```
   $line = <INFILE>;
```

twice. You do not need to have the second `$line = <INFILE>` in your code.